# Uncaught Error: Class 'combox' not found

Tags: php, html, jquery, bootstrap

Estoy revisando un codigo que parece que esta bien pero por alguna razon este error esta dando, no logro ubicar el porque considerando que breadcrumb funciona perfecto en los otros links pero con Visitas.php tira el error escrito

El codigo del menu (Llamado menu.require) es el siguiente, fue colocado en un JSFiddle para que pueda ser observado, este es el que manda la ID del usuario del perfil a las demas url
https://jsfiddle.net/sk4n97yj/

Visitas.php contiene el siguiente codigo, el cual llama a breadcrump.php para mostrar los datos que requiere, usando a breadcrump.php como una funcion

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){

        header('location:login.php');      
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="es" ng-app>
    <head>
        <!--  Require Gobal -->
        <?php require("../require/head.require.php"); ?>
        <!-- CSS -->
        <?php require("../require/css.require.php"); ?>
        <?php require("../require/insidecss.require.php"); ?>                
    </head> 
    <body>
        <!--  Require Variables -->
        <?php require("../require/get.require.php"); ?>
        <?php require("../require/function.require.php"); ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>


        <!--  GLobal -->
        <div class="page-wrap">
          <!--  Menu -->
          <?php require("../require/menu.require.php"); ?>

          <div class="container-fluid padding-container">            
            <!-- Breadcrumb -->
            <?php require("../require/breadcrumb.php"); ?>
            <!-- Border General -->
            <div class="border-1-oscuro padding-10">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <form class="formPaddign" id="formCaddpaquetes">
                        <div class="row">

                            <input type="hidden" id="Id_usuario" name="Id_usuario" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">

                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <div class="form-group"> 
                                    <h4>Historial de Visitas</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                <div class="row">

                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        <label>Mostrar todos Los Resultados</label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="filtro" id="tResultados"checked="checked" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        <label>Mostrar rango de fecha</label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="filtro" id="fResultados" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-3 mb-md-2">
                                        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" name="datetimepicker1">
                                            <input type='text'  class="form-control" name="Fecha_inicio" id="Fecha_inicio" placeholder="Fecha Inicio"  autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly" />
                                            <span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="$('#Fecha_inicio').dblclick();">
                                                <span class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2" name="datetimepicker2">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Fecha_fin" id="Fecha_fin" placeholder="Fecha Fin" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly"/>
                                            <span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="$('#Fecha_fin').dblclick();">
                                                <span class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="tab-content col-md-12">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade show active table-responsive table-sm" id="lista" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="dia-tab">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>            
            </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

        <!--  Footer -->
        <?php require("../require/footer.require.php"); ?>

        <!--  Modal -->
        <?php
            $modal = 'verHistorialVisitas';
            require("../require/modal.require.php");
        ?>   

        <!-- JS -->
        <?php require("../require/js.require.php"); ?>
        <?php require("../require/insidejs.require.php"); ?>
        <!-- JS -->
        <script>

        $('#Fecha_inicio').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
            weekStart : 0, 
            time: false,
            format : 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            triggerEvent: 'dblclick',
        });

        $('#Fecha_fin').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
            weekStart : 0, 
            time: false,
            format : 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            triggerEvent: 'dblclick',
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){

            buscarVisitaUsuario();    

            $("#tResultados").change(function(){
                buscarVisitaUsuario();              
            });

            $("#fResultados").change(function(){
                buscarVisitaUsuario();                 
            });

            $("#Fecha_inicio").change(function(){
                buscarVisitaUsuario();             
            });


            $("#Fecha_fin").change(function(){
                buscarVisitaUsuario();          
            });


        });



        function buscarVisitaUsuario(){


            var isChecked = document.getElementById('tResultados').checked;

            if(isChecked){
                Resultados = 1;
            }else{
                Resultados = 0;
            }


            datos = { 
                "opcion"  : "buscarVisitas",
                "id_usuario": $('#Id_usuario').val(),
                "resultado":Resultados,
                "fecha_inicio":$('#Fecha_inicio').val(),
                "fecha_fin":$('#Fecha_fin').val()
            };
              // console.dir(datos);

            $.ajax({
                url:'../controllers/perfilClienteController.php',
                type:'POST',
                data: datos

            }).done(function(response){
                // console.dir(response);
                // console.dir(JSON.parse(response));
                var data = JSON.parse(response).respuesta;
                var msj = JSON.parse(response).msj;
                var success = JSON.parse(response).success; 

                html="<table class='table table-bordered table-hover'><thead><tr><td><strong>Fecha</strong></td><td><strong>Hora</strong></td><td><strong>Clase</strong></td><td><strong>Estatus</strong></td><td><strong>Sede</strong></td><td><strong>Paquete/Plan</strong></td></tr></thead><tbody>";

                if(success){

                    var valores = eval(data);

                    for(i=0;i<valores.length;i++){

                        datos=valores[i][0]+"*"+valores[i][1]+"*"+valores[i][2]+"*"+valores[i][3]+"*"+valores[i][4]+"*"+valores[i][5]+"*"+valores[i][6]+"*"+valores[i][7]+"*"+valores[i][8]+"*"+valores[i][9]+"*"+valores[i][10]+"*"+valores[i][11]+"*"+valores[i][12]+"*"+valores[i][13]+"*"+valores[i][14]+"*"+valores[i][15]+"*"+valores[i][16]+"*"+valores[i][17];

                        html+="<tr data-toggle='modal' data-target='#Historial_visitas' style='cursor:pointer;' onclick='mostrar("+'"'+datos+'"'+");'><td>"+valores[i][0]+" "+valores[i][15]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][1]+"-"+valores[i][2]+"</td><td><a href='register.php?clase="+valores[i][16]+"'>"+valores[i][3]+"</a></td><td>"+valores[i][17]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][4]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][8]+"</td></tr>";

                    }

                    html+="</tbody></table>"

                    $("#lista").html(html);

                }else{

                    html+="<tr><td colspan='7'>"+msj+"</td></tr></tbody></table>"

                    $("#lista").html(html);
                }     

            });


        }

        function mostrar(datos){
            var d=datos.split("*");
            $("#Fecha").html(d[0]);
            $("#Hora").html(d[1]+"-"+d[2]);
            $("#Clase").html(d[3]);
            $("#Instructor").html(d[5]+" "+d[6]);
            $("#Sede").html(d[4]);
            $("#Salon").html(d[7]);
            $("#Asistio").html(d[9]);
            $("#Lista_espera").html(d[10]);
            $("#Cancelacion_tardia").html(d[11]);
            $("#Plan").html(d[8]);
            $("#Creador").html(d[12]+" "+d[13]+"("+d[14]+")");

        }


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

El codigo de breadcumb.php es el siguiente, tiene un problema en la linea 452, no obtiene el objeto llamado combox. Debido a lo largo del codigo, tuve que colocarlo en JSFiddle para su comprension debido al limite de 30000 caracteres de la pregunta

https://jsfiddle.net/1zwbschk/

Comment: Ten en cuenta que si quisiste poner mas de 30000 caracteres de codigo, algo no estaba bien ;) mejor mira [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP no puede encontrar la clase `combox`, es necesario que ubiques el archivo que contiene dicha clase y que sea incluido en tu código ANTES de ser usada.

Puedes hacer una búsqueda en todos los archivos desde Notepad ++ para que sea sencillo ubicarla en caso de que no tengas idea de donde esté.

Comment: Lo extraño es que el resto del codigo funciona bien, hare lo que dijiste

Comment: Funciono, a la persona se le olvido referenciar ese archivo